# MethodInfo.Invoke (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) on calling static method in abstract class

Tags: c#, reflection, abstract

I am trying to replicate a functionality with reflection but end up getting

> createFormatMethod.Invoke(typDbFormatClass, null)' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'    object {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}

Inner Exception Shows `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
System.NullReferenceException

InnerException null

Stacktrace

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at AB.INIT.stringToValue(String valueInUnits, String dimension, String sourceUnit, String destinationUnit)
```

I am trying to access a static method of abstract class here. Below is the direct reference code that works perfectly .

```
Binit.Core.Database.DbFormat format;
format = Binit.Core.Database.DbFormat.Create();
format.Dimension = DbDoubleDimension.GetDimension(
                   (DbDimension)Enum.Parse(typeof(DbDimension), dimension));
format.Units = DbDoubleUnits.GetUnits(
                (DbUnits)Enum.Parse(typeof(DbUnits), destinationUnit));
```

Reflection Code which fails and shows targetinvocationexception

```
Assembly CoreDatabaseAssembly = 
         Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(APath, @"Binit.Core.Database.dll"));

Type typDbFormatClass = CoreDatabaseAssembly.GetType("Binit.Core.Database.DbFormat");

MethodInfo createFormatMethod = typDbFormatClass.GetMethod("Create", 
           BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { }, null);

object objDbFormat = createFormatMethod.Invoke(typDbFormatClass, null);
```

Can someone help me understand what i could be doing wrong with invoke method

Comment: `TargetInvocationException` is a generic exception that is thrown for a lot of reflection calls if the underlying called code throws.  The `InnerException` will tell you what the original issue is, and that's what's important here.

Comment: Thanks . updated it with inner exception and that is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you check and ensure `typDbFormatClass.GetMethod` does not return null?

Comment: i checked it to find that its not null.